# Micron M25P80 Device Driver

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, spi, flash-memory

Has anyone ever used this driver? What headers do you need to include? I cannot find declarations of function implemented in the m25p80.c file in the kernel code include headers. What structs need to be filled and what functions called to perform read and write to Micron SD Card connected to microprocessor via SPI?

If possible please provide any example code you have/can find.

In Kernel: drivers/mtd/devices/m25p80.c

To Xilinx kernel location: https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/drivers/mtd/devices/m25p80.c

Answer (score 0):

I understand you must be using dts description for the board. In your DTS file, you can include support for this flash under SPI controller node by adding below lines:

```
  spi@8800D000 {
            /* your SPI Controller Node settings here  */
            /* Add / Modify/ delete below settings as per your HW  */
            compatible = "your compatible string";
            reg = <0x1000d000 0x1000>;
            num-cs = <0x4>;
            clocks = <0x2>;
            interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x86 0x4>;
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;

            nor@0 {
                    compatible = "n25q00";
                    reg = <0x0>;
                    spi-max-frequency = <25000000>;
                    spi-rx-bus-width = <0x4>;
                    spi-tx-bus-width = <0x4>;
                    #address-cells = <0x1>;
                    #size-cells = <0x1>;
                    partition@0 {
                            label = "part1";
                            reg = <0x0 0x000c0000>;
                    };

                    partition@c0000 {
                            label = "part2";
                            reg = <0x000c0000 0x00020000>;
                    };
            };
    };
```

Also Make sure you have enabled all the related kernel config for the same. like:

```
CONFIG_MTD_M25P80=y
CONFIG_MTD_SPI_NOR=y
CONFIG_MTD_SPI_NOR_USE_4K_SECTORS=y (if required)
CONFIG_SPI=y
CONFIG_SPI_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_SPI_MASTER=y
```

Also, enable your SPI controller.
If all the settings are correct, it will be probed and you can see the partitions being listed.

Comment: I'll try it. There is also the issue of the ability of QEMU to emulate an n25q00. I know that QEMU will support n25p80 card. I am trying to do this whole thing inside a QEMU emulation.